# Windows shell command to get the full path to the current directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there a Windows command line command that I can use to get the full path to the current working directory?

Also, how can I store this path inside a variable used in a batch file?

Answer (score 570, accepted):

Use `cd` with no arguments if you're using the shell directly, or `%cd%` if you want to use it in a batch file (it behaves like an environment variable).

Answer (score 133):

You can set a batch/environment variable as follows:

```
SET var=%cd%
ECHO %var%
```

sample screenshot from a Windows 7 x64 cmd.exe.

[image]

***Update:*** if you do a `SET var = %cd%` instead of `SET var=%cd%` , below is what happens. Thanks to jeb.

[image]

[Capturing the current directory from a batch file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/28/362565.aspx)

Comment: also simply `echo %cd%` will work

Answer (score 59):

Quote the Windows help for the `set` command (`set /?`):

```
If Command Extensions are enabled, then there are several dynamic
environment variables that can be expanded but which don't show up in
the list of variables displayed by SET.  These variable values are
computed dynamically each time the value of the variable is expanded.
If the user explicitly defines a variable with one of these names, then
that definition will override the dynamic one described below:

%CD% - expands to the current directory string.

%DATE% - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.

%TIME% - expands to current time using same format as TIME command.

%RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.

%ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value

%CMDEXTVERSION% - expands to the current Command Processor Extensions
    version number.

%CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original command line that invoked the
    Command Processor.
```

Note the **`%CD% - expands to the current directory string.`** part.

Answer (score 36):

On Unix?

pwd

Comment: OP originally asked for a "command" and didn't specify OS. OS has now been specified so this answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 34):

This has always worked for me:

```
SET CurrentDir="%~dp0"

ECHO The current file path this bat file is executing in is the following:

ECHO %CurrentDir%

Pause
```

Comment: That does the wrong thing - finds the path of the batch script, not the current directory.

Comment: Nice catch. Current directory could refer to the command that call the file instead of the file's location itself.

Comment: %cd% is the wrong answer. If launching a CMD window with admin access, the directory shows as %windir%\system32\. %~dp0% shows the appropriate directory, even if in an admin launched CMD window.

Answer (score 27):

For Windows we can use

`cd`

and for Linux

`pwd`

command is there.

Comment: ```cd``` in PowerShell moves back to ```c:\users\[me]``` regardless of the current path

Answer (score 12):

Create a `.bat` file under `System32`, let us name it `copypath.bat` the command to copy current path *could be*:

```
echo %cd% | clip
```

**Explanation:** 
`%cd%` will give you current path

```
CLIP

Description:
    Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard.
    This text output can then be pasted into other programs.

Parameter List:
    /?                  Displays this help message.

Examples:
    DIR | CLIP          Places a copy of the current directory
                        listing into the Windows clipboard.

    CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt
                        on to the Windows clipboard.
```

Now `copypath` is available from everywhere.

Comment: You can just "cd | clip" to copy current path to the clipboard

Answer (score 11):

***On Windows:***

**CHDIR**    Displays the name of or changes the current directory.

***In Linux:***

**PWD**      Displays the name of current directory.

Answer (score 9):

For Windows, `cd` by itself will show you the current working directory.

For UNIX and workalike systems, `pwd` will perform the same task.  You can also use the `$PWD` shell variable under some shells.  I am not sure if Windows supports getting the current working directory via a shell variable or not.

Comment: I can't however understand why he needs "cd" to see his current dir. By default, it is visible as day. And if he's changed it, than he certainly knows what "cd" does.

Comment: very old, but just for completeness: yes, windows does have a varible for this. It's named (guess...) `%cd%`

Answer (score 5):

Based on the follow up question (store the data in a variable) in the comments to the chdir post I'm betting he wants to store the current path to restore it after changeing directories.

The original user should look at "pushd", which changes directory and pushes the current one onto a stack that can be restored with a "popd". On any modern Windows cmd shell that is the way to go when making batch files.

If you really need to grab the current path then modern cmd shells also have a %CD% variable that you can easily stuff away in another variable for reference.

Answer (score 4):

In a Windows command prompt, `chdir` or `cd` will print the full path of the current working directory in the console.

If we want to copy the path then we can use: `cd | clip`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`chdir`) do set var=%%x
echo The currenct directory is: %var%
```

But, *of course*, gmaran23's answer is the much easier one.

Comment: His answer is better by definition because your answer is wrong. It does not work for paths with spaces.

Comment: Adding `tokens=*` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, type `cd` for the working current path.

On Linux, `pwd` for the current working path.

Answer (score -1):

As one of the possible codes

```
    echo off
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%x in (`chdir`) do set var=%var% %%x
    echo The current directory is: "%var:~1%"
```