# How do I activate a virtualenv inside PyCharm's terminal?

Tags: python, shell, pycharm, virtualenv

I've set up PyCharm, created my virtualenv (either through the virtual env command, or directly in PyCharm) and activated that environment as my Interpreter. Everything is working just fine.

However, if I open a terminal using "Tools, Open Terminal", the shell prompt supplied is *not* using the virtual env; I still have to use `source ~/envs/someenv/bin/activate` within that Terminal to activate it.

Another method is to activate the environment in a shell, and run PyCharm from that environment. This is "workable" but pretty ugly, and means I have major problems if I switch environments or projects from PyCharm: I'm now using the totally-wrong environment.

Is there some other, much-easier way to have "Tools, Open Terminal" automatically activate the virtual environment?

Comment: ## Simple, re-start your PyCharm to see the virtualenv in your PyCharm terminal.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

***Edit:***

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#v2016-3-venv-in-terminal, PyCharm 2016.3 (released Nov 2016) has virutalenv support for terminals out of the box

> Auto virtualenv is supported for bash, zsh, fish, and Windows cmd. You
> can customize your shell preference in Settings (Preferences) | Tools
> | Terminal | check Activate virtaulenv

you also need to make sure to have the path of virtual environment path included in the content root folder of your project structure. You can go to settings (preference) | project | Project Structure |  if your environment is not included in the project directory.

---

***Old Method:***

Create a file `.pycharmrc` in your home folder with the following contents

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/pycharmvenv/bin/activate
```

Use your virtualenv path as the last parameter.

Then set the shell Preferences->Project Settings->Shell path to

```
/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of overriding the shell's rc file.

To better support pycharm working with multiple projects, each which might have a different virtualenv, I'd call the ".pycharmrc" file something different, and perhaps put it into the env directory itself. ```~/pycharmenv/bin/terminalactivate``` sounds like a good option.

Comment: @PeterGibson, pferate's answer has nothing to do with the OP's question. The problem is terminal not the Python interpreter. The venv integration has been there way before PyCharm 4. Your answer works though.

Comment: @norbertpy I hadn't tested it so thanks for the update

Comment: This is the simplest solution, except that I place my `.pycharmrc` in the project home folder, so that I can have a different file for each project. In a properly configured project, there is no need to provide the absolute path to the `.pycharmrc` file.

Comment: At least for macOS you have to add `-i` option after `--rcfile` to enable interactive mode or your `~/.pycharmrc` will not be executed. Here is what `man bash` says about `--rcfile` option: `Execute  commands  from  file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive`

Comment: macos 10.12.2, pycharm 2016.3.2     `/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc` or `/bin/bash --rcfile -i ~/.pycharmrc` not work for me   @renskiy

Comment: @SiminJie, try this one: `/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc -i`

Comment: @renskiy `/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc -i` return `bash: /Users/username/pycharmvenv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
`  -- Pycharm version 2016.3.2

Comment: @SiminJie, PyCharm 2016.3.2 has such option from the box. Go to the: settings -> Tools -> Terminal. And make sure "Activate virtualenv" option is enabled.

Comment: also I used 
`source \`pwd\`/.env/bin/activate` 
instead of second line, It made me able to use same `rc` file for other projects too.

Comment: @pferate @norbertpy @renskiy
The Tools -> Terminal -> Activate virtual env solution works if I want to do `bash script.sh` in PyCharm terminal.

But I am not able to  make the virtualenv effective  for the case when I right click on bash file and select `Run script.sh`. When I run this way, it doesn't respect the virtualenv.

I can add virtual env for Python type run configurations, but couldn't find how to set virtual env for Bash type run configuration.

Running `script.sh` as a before launch activity inside a virtual environment set Python run configuration doesn't work either.
Help

Comment: well for now I just did this hack where I activated the virtual env in my `script.sh` itself by adding these lines:

```source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
workon <venvname>```

Comment: Is this option only available in PyCharm but not IntelliJ IDEA? I went to Settings -> Tools -> Terminal but there is no option related to virtual env.

Comment: @xji I expect you'd need to use the Python specific PyCharm

Comment: Still you have to be careful with PyCharm's terminal. I polluted my host's python dependencies because I believed that PyCharm was intelligent enough to automatically activate the venv in the console.

Answer (score 61):

***Update:***

The preferences in Settings (Preferences) | Tools | Terminal are global.
If you use a venv for each project, remember to use current path variable and a default venv name:

```
"cmd.exe" /k ""%CD%\venv\Scripts\activate""
```

---

For Windows users: when using PyCharm with a virtual environment, you can use the `/K` parameter to `cmd.exe` to set the virtual environment automatically.

PyCharm 3 or 4: `Settings`, `Terminal`, `Default shell` and add `/K <path-to-your-activate.bat>`.

PyCharm 5: `Settings`, `Tools`, `Terminal`, and add `/K <path-to-your-activate.bat>` to `Shell path`.

PyCharm 2016.1 or 2016.2: `Settings`, `Tools`, `Terminal`, and add `""/K <path-to-your-activate.bat>""` to `Shell path` and add (mind the quotes). Also add quotes around cmd.exe, resulting in:

`"cmd.exe" /k ""C:\mypath\my-venv\Scripts\activate.bat""`

Comment: In this case `%CD%` is the current working directory, see [Windows shell command to get the full path to the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607682)

Comment: is there a reason you're using double-double quotes around the bat address?

Comment: @Nick I do not recall, this is from over 8y ago :-) Meanwhile the other answer is more relevant (since the 2016.03 release). All I know is that it worked with double double quotes, I don't remember testing it with single double quotes.

Answer (score 43):

For Windows users when using PyCharm and a virtual environment under Windows, you can use the /k parameter to cmd.exe to set the virtual environment automatically.

Go to Settings, Terminal, Default shell and add `/K <path-to-your-activate.bat>`.

I don't have the reputation to comment on the earlier response so posting this corrected version. This really saves a LOT of time.

**Update:**

Note: Pycharm now supports virtual environments directly and it seems to work well for me - so my workaround not needed anymore.

Comment: This is great, but only when you have just one virtualenv for all your projects. Default shell setting is shared across projects

Answer (score 41):

Somehow a small trick worked for me. All you gotta do is change the default terminal from Power shell to CMD.

1. **Open pycharm --> Go to Settings --> Tools --> Terminal**
2. **Change the `Shell Path` to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` from `PS`**
3. **Check the `Activate virtualenv` checkbox**
4. **Hit `apply` and open new terminal**

It's 2021 you don't need to specify the file path or add the environment variable.

**Update: It's 2022 and I run into the same issue**
Fix: Follow the above steps and in addition, make sure you have selected the **Your virtual env python.exe as your project python interpreter, and that's it**

Comment: This works. The terminal on the pycharm run as it were original windows command prompt after applying the above settings.

Answer (score 9):

If You are using windows version it is quite easy.
If you already have the virtual environment just navigate to its folder, find `activate.bat` inside `Scripts` folder. copy it's **full** path and paste it in pycharm's terminal then press `Enter` and you're done!

If you need to create new virtual environment :

Go to files > settings then search for `project interpreter`, open it, click on gear button and create the environment wherever you want and then follow first paragraph.

[image: The Gear!]

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Quick question. I have 3 different virtual environments that I created in Anaconda. Is there separate `activate.bat` for each of them?

Comment: @user1700890 yes! In case you haven't overwritten the environments, they should have separate folders and as a result, separate `activate.bat` files. if you like the answer, feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: Thank you, I just checked, there are no folders in `Scripts` folder. Also Pycharm complains that `activate.bat` is not a valid python SDK

Comment: So i think you should first try and find the virtual-environment folder created when you where using Anaconda and then run the `activate` batch file inside it. or if it is possible for you, just go with creating a new environment.

Comment: The last step which finally helped me after above instructions - is to close duplicate Terminal tab I created accidentally before.  Settings wasn't applying for it for some reason. Original one became ok.

Answer (score 8):

I have viewed all of the answers above but none of them is elegant enough for me. In PyCharm 2017.1.3 (in my computer), the easiest way is to open `Settings->Tools->Terminal` and check `Shell integration` and `Activate virtualenv` options.

[image]

Comment: Well, the accepted answer quotes this very same thing. Its just that it doesn't have picture.

Answer (score 7):

Based on answers from Peter and experimentation, I've come up with a good "general solution", which solves the following:

- Restores the behaviour of a login shell. PyCharm normally runs a login shell, but --rcfile stopped this happening. Script still uses --rcfile, but attempts to emulate the INVOCATION behaviour of a login shell.
- Removes the need to create an rcfile for each environment
- Removes the need to update the project settings if you change the environment.

Drop this script into a bin directory somewhere. E.g. ~/bin/pycharmactivate

```
if [ -r "/etc/profile" ] ; then . /etc/profile ; fi
if [ -r "~/.bash_profile" ] ; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
elif [ -r "~/.bash_login" ] ; then
    . ~/.bash_login
elif [ -r "~/.profile" ] ; then
    . ~/.profile
fi
ACTIVATERC=`cat .idea/workspace.xml | perl -n -e 'print "\$1/bin/activate" if m:option name="SDK_HOME" value="\\\$USER_HOME\\\$(.*)/bin/python":'`
if [ -n "$ACTIVATERC" ] ; then . "$HOME/$ACTIVATERC" ; else echo "Could not find virtualenv from PyCharm" ; fi
```

Then set PyCharm's Shell path to:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile ~/bin/pycharmactivate
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked for me after hours of unsuccessful attempts to figure out where to start bashrc and bash profiles. However it threw and error that it could'nt find my virtual env so I modified it like so, can you tell me if it's OK?

`if [ -r "/etc/profile" ] ; then . /etc/profile ; fi
if [ -r "~/.bash_profile" ] ; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
elif [ -r "~/.bash_login" ] ; then
    . ~/.bash_login
elif [ -r "~/.profile" ] ; then
    . ~/.profile
fi
source ~/learnp/project1/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: @zerohedge: Your script will work fine, but it's fixed to your "project1" virtualenv. The script above was supposed to do auto-detection, but there's a bunch of assumptions being made: that the initial working directory is the location of the ".idea" directory; that the format of the workspace.xml file doesn't change significantly. Unfortunately, it looks like pycharm version 5 has made significant changes in that area. I can't actually figure out where the data is, now.

Comment: well I don't mind changing my addition depending on the project, since the Shell Path to is also project specific. I could only get a prompt saying "bash 3.2$:" before finding your script, with no indication of my current directory or any resemblance of my Terminal prompt. Thank you again!

Answer (score 7):

PyCharm 4 now has virtualenvs integrated in the IDE.  When selecting your project interpreter, you can create, add, or select a virtualenv.  They've added a "Python Console" that runs in the configured project interpreter.

[More info here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-virtual-environment.html)

Comment: How does this answer the OP? Still have to `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate` manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Chris, your script worked for some projects but not all on my machine. Here is a script that I wrote and I hope anyone finds it useful.

```
#Stored in ~/.pycharmrc 

ACTIVATERC=$(python -c 'import re
import os
from glob import glob

try:
  #sets Current Working Directory to _the_projects .idea folder
  os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/.idea") 

  #gets every file in the cwd and sets _the_projects iml file
  for file in glob("*"): 
    if re.match("(.*).iml", file):
      project_iml_file = file

  #gets _the_virtual_env for _the_project
  for line in open(project_iml_file):
    env_name = re.findall("~/(.*)\" jdkType", line.strip())
    # created or changed a virtual_env after project creation? this will be true
    if env_name:
      print env_name[0] + "/bin/activate"
      break

    inherited = re.findall("type=\"inheritedJdk\"", line.strip())
    # set a virtual_env during project creation? this will be true
    if inherited:
      break

  # find _the_virtual_env in misc.xml
  if inherited:
    for line in open("misc.xml").readlines():
      env_at_project_creation = re.findall("\~/(.*)\" project-jdk", line.strip())
      if env_at_project_creation:
        print env_at_project_creation[0] + "/bin/activate"
        break
finally:
  pass
')

if [ "$ACTIVATERC" ] ; then . "$HOME/$ACTIVATERC" ; fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Had to do two additional things though.     1) Add `source /etc/profile` at the beginning of ~/.pycharmrc file (on Mac Yosemite)      2) In Pycharm edit Preferences > Tools > Terminal > Shell path to "/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc"

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! If you're using Python 3, remember to put parentheses for the print function. I myself had to put "export ~/.bashrc" before this script.

Answer (score 5):

If you have moved your project to another directory, you can set the new path via Settings dialog. And then you need to set this Project Interpreter in the Edit Configuration dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also had to restart PyCharm for the "Activate virtualenv" setting to kick in again. Opening an new terminal tab was not enough.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac it's **PyCharm => Preferences... => Tools => Terminal => Activate virtualenv**, which should be enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

I just added a script named pycharmactivate to my home directory. Set value of PyCharm (4.0.1) File > Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path  to /bin/bash --rcfile ~/pycharmactivate.
Maybe not the best solution incase you have different project and virtualenv directories/names but it works for me. This script contains the following 3 lines and assumes your virtualenv has the same name as your project dir.

```
source ~/.bashrc
projectdir=${PWD##*/}
source ~/.virtualenvs/$projectdir/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 2):

this is what i am doing:
create a activate_env.bat(windows,maybe  .sh in linux) file in the source code folde:

```
/env_yourenvlocate/scripts/activate.bat
```

and another file deactivate_env.bat:

```
/env_yourenvlocate/scripts/deactivate.bat
```

everytime  open the terminal window, just execute the bat file to activate/deactivate the virtualenv, you will stay in source code path, no need to change path to and back.

```
E:\Projects\django_study\src>active_env.bat

E:\Projects\django_study\src>../env_django_study/scripts/activate.bat
(env_django_study) E:\Projects\django_study\src>



(env_django_study) E:\Projects\django_study\src>deactive_env.bat

(env_django_study)E:\Projects\django_study\src>../env_django_study/scripts/deactivate.bat
E:\Projects\django_study\src>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Peter's answer,
here the Mac version of the `.pycharmrc` file:

```
source /etc/profile
source ~/.bash_profile
source  <venv_dir>/bin/activate
```

Hen

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for WSL (Ubuntu on Windows)**

If you're using WSL (Ubuntu on Windows), you can also open bash as terminal in pycharm and activate a linux virtualenv.

Use a `.pycharmrc` file like described in Peter Gibson's answer; Add the `.pycharmrc` file to your home directory with following content:

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/path_to_virtualenv/bin/activate
```

In Pycharm *File > Settings > Tools > Terminal* add the following 'Shell path':

```
"C:/Windows/system32/bash.exe" -c "bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc"
```

**Project specific virtualenv**

The path to your virtualenv in `.pycharmrc` does not have to be absolute. You can set a project specific virtualenv by setting a relative path from your project directory.
My virtualenv is always located in a 'venv' folder under my project directory, so my `.pycharmrc` file looks like this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/pycharmvenv/bin/activate #absolute path
source ./venv/bin/activate #relative path
```

**BONUS: automatically open ssh tunnel to connect virtualenv as project interpreter**

Add the following to your `.pycharmrc` file:

```
if [ $(ps -aux | grep -c 'ssh') -lt 2 ]; then
    sudo service ssh start 
fi
```

This checks if a ssh tunnel is already opened, and opens one otherwise.
In *File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter* in Pycharm, add a new remote interpreter with following configuration:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+-------+----+
| Name:                    | <Interpreter name>              |       |    |
| Select                   | 'SSH Credentials'               |       |    |
| Host:                    | 127.0.0.1                       | Port: | 22 |
| User:                    | <Linux username>                |       |    |
| Auth type:               | 'Password'                      |       |    |
| Password:                | <Linux password>                |       |    |
| Python interpreter path: | <Linux path to your virtualenv> |       |    |
| Python helpers path:     | <Set automatically>             |       |    |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+-------+----+
```

Now when you open your project, your bash automatically starts in your virtualenv, opens a ssh tunnel, and pycharm connects the virtualenv as remote interpreter.

*warning: the last update in Windows automatically starts a SshBroker and SshProxy service on startup. These block the ssh tunnel from linux to windows. You can stop these services in Task Manager -> Services, after which everything will work again.*

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. As someone who enjoys Debian but is too lazy to set up a second OS, I cannot thank you enough. I would like to add that the activate script provided to me by Pycharm ended up needing to be run through dos2unix before it would run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with **venv** in PyCharm. But It is not big problem!
Just do:

1. enter in your terminal venv directory( **cd venv/Scripts/** )
2. You will see **activate.bat**
3. Just enter activate.bat in your terminal after this you will see YOUR ( venv )

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem of not having venv activated in pycharm terminal (**Pycharm version 2021.2.2**). Just simply follow the steps below.

Go to "settings -> tools -> terminal" then at the bottom of that window check if "Activate virtualenv" is having a tick or not, if not then make sure that box is ticked.

Then in the middle part of that window check the the shell path is set to "cmd.exe" or not, if not then set it to "cmd.exe" (it will have it's path associated with it so no need to do anything just click on "cmd.exe" from the drop down list) then click on "apply" button below and click "ok".

Now it's done, just close your opened terminal and re-open it. You will see "venv" in front of your project path.

P.S: Don't mind the double quotes in my answer they are just for highlighting the texts, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Simple and Easy Solution:**

1. In Pycharm inside the Projects menu on the left there will be folders.
2. Find the Scripts folder
3. Inside there you'll find activate.bat
4. Right click on activate.bat
5. Copy/Path Reference
6. Select Absolute Path
7. Find the Terminal tab located in the middle at the bottom of Pycharm.
8. Paste it into the terminal console and press enter
9. If you did it right the terminal path will have brackets (venv) around the name of the folder you activated.
10. Before: "PS C:\"
11. After: "(venv) C:\"
12. *Note* The folder name may be different than yours the  important part is the (brackets) :D

Comment: not working . it is PS still please help

Comment: I got the answer you should use the file activate.ps1 for powershell and activate.bat for cmd prompt

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, this is how I solved it:

All you gotta do is change the default terminal from Power shell to CMD.
Open pycharm --> Go to Settings --> Tools --> Terminal.
Change the Shell Path to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe from PS.
Check the Activate virtualenv checkbox.
Hit apply and open new terminal.

Comment: This is by far the simplest yet workable answer I saw on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that worked on my Windows 7 machine.

I believe PyCharm's terminal is a result of it running `cmd.exe`, which will load the Windows `PATH` variable, and use the version of Python that it finds first within that `PATH`. To edit this variable, right click *My Computer* --> *Properties* --> *Advanced System Settings* --> *Advanced* tab --> *Environment Variables...* button. Within the *System variables* section, select and edit the `PATH` variable.

Here is the relevant part of my `PATH` **before** editing:

> C:\Python27\;
>   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\;
>   C:\Python27\Scripts;
>   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;

...and **after** editing `PATH` (only 3 lines now):

> C:[project_path]\virtualenv-Py2.7_Dj1.7\Lib\site-packages\pip;
>   C:[project_path]\virtualenvs\virtualenv-Py2.7_Dj1.7\Scripts;
>   C:[project_path]\virtualenvs\virtualenv-Py2.7_Dj1.7\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;

To test this, open a **new** windows terminal (*Start* --> type in `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and see if it's using your virtual environment. If that works, **restart PyCharm** and then test it out in PyCharm's terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If your Pycharm 2016.1.4v and higher you should use
`"default path" /K "<path-to-your-activate.bat>"`
don't forget quotes

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you have already have the virtualenvironment eg. 'myvenv' located within the project root, you can activate it from the terminal as below:

```
.\myvenv\Scripts\activate
```

Calling the activate from the virtualenv you desire to activate, activates the virtualenv.

You know it is activated when you see the change:

```
C:\Projects\Trunk\MyProject>
```

to

```
(myvenv)C:\Projects\Trunk\MyProject>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows with wsl2, the only thing that worked for me (November 2022) was:

1. go into Pycharm terminal definition
2. paste:

`wsl.exe -- bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; source <path-to-your-virtial-env>/bin/activate')`

inside the 'Shell path' box.

Then every time you open the terminal the virtual environment would be activated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage your virtual environments. It appears that once the virtualenvwrapper [script is activated](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file), pycharm can use that and then the simple `workon` command will be available from the pycharm console and present you with the available virtual environments:

```
kevin@debian:~/Development/django-tutorial$ workon
django-tutorial
FlaskHF
SQLAlchemy
themarkdownapp
kevin@debian:~/Development/django-tutorial$ workon django-tutorial
(django-tutorial)kevin@debian:~/Development/django-tutorial$
```

Comment: However, that requires me have to activate the workon script every time I open the terminal, _and_ know which virtual environment pycharm is currently using for running the program, both of which I was explicitly trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This method should work with arbitrary virtual environments per project and it doesn't make assumptions on your environment as it is using hooks you create.

You write:

- A global script that invokes the hook
- A hook script per PyCharm project (not mandatory)

Given that the current latest PyCharm (Community 2016.1) does not allow for Terminal settings *per project* start with the script that invokes the project specific hook. This is my `~/.pycharmrc`:

```
if [ -r ".pycharm/term-activate" ]; then
   echo "Terminal activation hook detected."
   echo "Loading Bash profile..."
   source ~/.bash_profile
   echo "Activating terminal hook..."
   source ".pycharm/term-activate"
   source activate $PYCHARM_VENV
fi
```

If you are using something other than Bash, invoke your own `.bash_profile` equivalent should you wish to.

Now set your PyCharm "Tools -> Terminal -> Shell Path" to invoke this script, e.g.: `/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc`

Finally, for every PyCharm project you need a specific virtual environment activated, create a file within the PyCharm project root `.pycharm/term-activate`. This is your hook and it will simply define the name of the desired virtual environment for your PyCharm project:

```
export PYCHARM_VENV=<your-virtual-env-name>
```

You can of course extend your hooks with anything you find useful in the terminal environment of your particular PyCharm project.

Answer (score 0):

For conda virtual environments on Windows, make sure your batch file is NOT named `activate.bat` as this will cause a conflict with the conda `activate` command, resulting in a recursive calling of the batch file.

What works for me is the following Shell path:

```
"cmd.exe" /k ""C:\FullPathToYourProject\activate-env.bat""
```

And in the activate-env.bat file:

```
call activate myenvname
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a separate virtual environment for each project, and didn't care much for having additional files to facilitate this. A solution which you only need to do once and works for all projects is then adding the following to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -d "./venv" ]; then
    source ./venv/bin/activate
fi
```

This checks if there is a virtual environment where the terminal is being opened, and if so activates it (and of course other relative paths could be used). PyCharm's terminal settings can be left as their default.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 4.5.4

> Create a file .pycharmrc in your home folder with the following
>   contents
>
> ```
> source ~/.bashrc
> source ~/pycharmvenv/bin/activate
> ```
>
> Using your virtualenv path as the last parameter.
>
> Then set the shell Preferences->Project Settings->Shell path to
>
> ```
> /bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc
> ```

I don't why, but it doesn't work for me. PyCharm prints an error.

`cmd.exe /K "<path-to-your-activate.bat>"` 
It works, but it creates the same virtualenv for each project, and even if this is not necessary.

This [receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378182/7290976) is working! But the string `/env_yourenvlocate/scripts/activate.bat` must contain quotes, like this `"Full_path_to_your_env_locate\scripts\activate.bat"`!

Deactivate the virtualenv is very easy - type in the terminal 'deactivate'

```
(virt_env) D:\Projects\src>deactivate
D:\Projects\src>
```

Comment: "I don't why, but it doesn't work for me" - maybe because this solution is good for linux/mac - not for windows ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option you have when you enter the terminal >
Run > Debug > Edit Configurations
[image]

[image]

select the appropriate conda environmnent..
Also when you create a new project - it asks to configure this location.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
As you can see, python interpreter is located in venv/bin/python. If you go to this folder, you will see all libraries listed in there
[image]
Sooo... as you will think, you use python command with it's path - that means in project path, for example

```bash
./venv/bin/pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Windows, I solved it by installing PowerShell 7 and selecting it in PyCharm on Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell Path using the new option that appeared after installing it.

`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe`

[PowerShell 7 - Install from Windows Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but this came up yesterday on my macos machine when the Intel dmg stopped working on my M1 after an update. I have activate checked, but it no longer activates the venv. In my case, I noticed it has then environment variable `JEDITERM_SOURCE` set to the activate path of my venv. I just added

```bash
[[ -n ${JEDITERM_SOURCE} ]] && source ${JEDITERM_SOURCE}
```

to then end of my `.profile` and it now activates again. I checked on two different projects and both activated the correct venv.

Answer (score -2):

Set an existing virtual environment﻿, Official Document: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html?keymap=secondary_macos#existing-environment