# Launch command line from pycharm with environment variables set

Tags: python, installation, pycharm

Is it possible to launch a command line prompt from pycharm that has all the environment variables set already (IE PYTHONPATH) for my projects custom environment.

Comment: This question looks like it might be helpful, if you're using VirtualEnv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal

Comment: This doesn't help launching from pycharm, but with a VirtualEnv set up I just created this batch file:
    `C:
    cd \path_to_project\
    call c:\path_to_virtualenv_environment\scripts\activate.bat
    start C:\path_to_bash\sh.exe --login`

I keep the batch file handy to launch.

Comment: No we are on windows environment, and @metsfan s solution is looking quite good at the moment, will try it out in the morning at work

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Run -> Edit Configurations` in PyCharm, this will let you set CLI arguments, and there's also a couple of different PYTHONPATH-related fields (`Add content roots to PYTHONPATH`, `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH`).  You can also right-click a folder under the Project menu and check `Mark as Sources Root` - which I believe adds this directory to the `PYTHONPATH` at PyCharm script run-time.

Also, like metsfansaid, you could create a batch file to populate your Windows PYTHONPATH environmental variables prior to running anything in the new environment.  I believe PyCharm will inherit those.

Comment: @BojanJovanovic you still having this issue?

Comment: nah pycharm fixed this a long time ago :)

Comment: and yeah source roots do the job