# How do setup virtualenv and dependencies in pycharm?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, pycharm

I am using a virtualenv on a remote machine and want simulate the same env on my mac so that I can use pycharm for further development.

My virtualenv is in the path , "~/venv"

I have created the ~/.pycharmc with following contents(as suggested in "[How do I activate a virtualenv inside PyCharm's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal)")

source ~/venv/bin/activate

> /bin/bash --rcfile ~/.pycharmrc

works fine and creates the necessary venv, but it is not working in my pycharm environment(attaching image at the end)

What am I missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Settings > Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters > Add`

Navigate to `~/venv/bin` and select your python binary. PyCharm notices that it is an virtual environment and supports it completely. Make sure to select the added environment as your projects interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had copied the virtualenv folders from the remote machine. Once I installed all the dependencies and added it in the list of virtualenvs of PyCharm. It works fine now .