# Run a command when the terminal opens in Intellij IDEA

Tags: django, intellij-idea, virtualenv

I have a Django project running in a virtualenv and I would like the terminal to run in that virtualenv when opened. At the moment I have to type `workon virtualenv` which isn't exactly the end of the world but I'm guessing there is a way to make this happen automatically?
Is there a way to run commands at startup like you can do with the django and python consoles?

Comment: are you on os x, windows or some linux?

Comment: Have you considered changing the path to the Python interpreter to the interpreter inside your virtualenv directory?

Comment: @tttthomasssss: linux

Comment: @schillingt: I already have

Comment: @eggbert try the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal

Answer (score 3):

As tttthomasssss suggested, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22289136/519074.
Only this answer worked, the ones below it didn't even though they look more useful.

Update - This is what worked for me:

For each virtualenv, put a file called something like terminalactivate.sh into /bin with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ~/.bashrc
source $(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd)/activate
```

Then in pycharm/idea settings choose this for shell path:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile ~/virtualenv/sff/bin/terminalactivate.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but if you're using fish shell, you can also do this with the -C flag. For example I use it to set a different theme on shells open inside intellij by setting shell path to:

`/opt/homebrew/bin/fish -C "fish_config theme choose 'Solarized Light'"`