# Pycharm includes too many libraries

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm

I've created a basic Flask project, but when I go to create a virtual environment there are a ton of libraries that have nothing to do with the dependencies listed in the Project Interpreter.  [image]

When I run 'pip freeze' these are all the dependencies in the project.  What am I missing?  I'm quite sure this handful of libraries does don't have all the following dependencies.  What am I missing? `BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
CacheControl==0.11.5
DateTime==4.0.1
Django==1.8.3
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.9.0
Pygments==2.0.2
Pyro4==4.38
Twisted==13.2.0
Werkzeug==0.10.4
altgraph==0.10.2
appnope==0.1.0
azure==0.11.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
boto==2.38.0
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2015.9.6.2
chardet==2.3.0
contextlib2==0.4.0
decorator==4.0.2
djangorestframework==3.1.3
elasticsearch==1.5.0
elasticsearch-dsl==0.0.4
funcsigs==0.4
functools32==3.2.3.post2
funcy==1.5
future==0.15.2
futures==3.0.3
gensim==0.12.0
gnureadline==6.3.3
ijson==2.1
incf.countryutils==1.0
ipykernel==4.0.3
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
joblib==0.8.4
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.0.0
jupyter-console==4.0.2
jupyter-core==4.0.5
langid==1.1.4.dev0
lockfile==0.10.2
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.4.3
mistune==0.7.1
mock==1.3.0
modulegraph==0.10.4
natsort==4.0.3
nbconvert==4.0.0
nbformat==4.0.0
nltk==3.0.2
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.0.4
numexpr==2.4.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
pandas==0.16.2
path.py==8.1.1
pbr==1.8.0
pexpect==3.3
pickleshare==0.5
ptyprocess==0.5
py2app==0.7.3
pyLDAvis==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pycountry==1.12
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
pyzmq==14.7.0
qtconsole==4.0.1
requests==2.6.0
scikit-bio==0.4.0
scipy==0.16.0
serpent==1.11
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simserver==0.1.4`

Comment: How did you create the virtual environment? Do you allow it access to global packages?

Comment: Try doing this in a pristine virtual environment instead.  The likely scenario is that you've been installing these packages via pip globally and they've leaked into your project.

Comment: I used PyCharm to create the virtual env.  And it does allow me to include or not include global dependencies.  I tried both options.

Comment: Where does the virtualenv live?  What happens when you run `pip freeze` from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running pip freeze in the terminal for PyCharm thinking that was running the virtual env.  I found this post that helps to work with virtualenv within Pycharm [How do I activate a virtualenv inside PyCharm's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal)

Comment: in other news the world now knows how sloppy I've been with my global library.  so there's that.