# Pycharm terminal doesn't use the venv

Tags: terminal, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a strange behavior.
I already have set up my 'project interpreter' and if I execute my script it will run with the venv.
The integrated terminal tool in PyCharm on the other doesn't run with the venv.
pip list will not return the python modules of my venv.

I already checked my settings and the box "activate virtualenv" is checked.

[image]

How can I force the terminal to work with the venv?
I would really like to just pip install missing modules into my venv and not elsewhere.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal

Comment: What research have you don so far? This SO page may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal

Comment: I use this version:
PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5
The answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569 does not solve my problem as far as I understood it, this is solved automatically for every newer version.

Well research wise I checked of course the documentation of how to set up the venv on the intellij website. I followed each construction but it doesn't help a all.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem as yours. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved somehow my own mysterium.
So there may be some issue with international windows os.
The activate.bat file which shall automatically activate the venv in the terminal within pycharm fails with a message of:
"Wrong Parameterformat- 850".
This can be seen if one just try to start the activate.bat in a command prompt.

The Solution to solve this is Here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue32409