# PyCharm - venv is not getting activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

I am learning Python and Django and want to activate the virtual environment from the PyCharm community edition 2019.3

I can see the venv created under my folder but when I try and activate it using the command

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

There's an error -

'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

I already tried checking the project interpreter and it seems to point to the right path.
Below is the screenshot

[image]

I have checked the below link as well -
[How do I activate a virtualenv inside PyCharm's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal)
and tried changing the terminal option, but somehow I am not getting rid of this error -

[image]

Can someone please help here?

Thanks,
Sanket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycharm automatically activates the virtual environment fo your project, see the `(venv)` in Pycharm terminal before the folder information.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was already activated and it is now running fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows, please use below to activate.

```
venv\scripts\activate
```

Comment: Hey Mayur, thanks for your reply! I am on windows, in the folder, I can see 3 activate files, .file, .bat, and .ps1. Which one should I use? Should I just open it or run through any command in PyCharm?

Comment: You should run activate.bat

Comment: Run the command `venv\scripts\activate`
 from pycharm terminal. But as I can see in your screenshot, it's already activated as pycharm automatically do that.