# How can i use a virtual environment that i created using cmd in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I created a virtual environment using cmd "virtualenv" code . But i need to know if there is any way we can use this created virtual environment in pycharm .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I activate a virtualenv inside PyCharm's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are 2 ways.

- Upon creation of the project
- After the creation of the project

Upon creation of the project:

Check the preciously configured interpreter->click on 3 dots and select the environment

[image]

After the creation of the project:

Go to File->settings...

[image]

Comment: do i need to add the file scripts/python.exe as the interpreter.

Comment: nope. IDE will handle it for you.
Just select the env.

Comment: i am not able to select the folder of the env. But when i choose the scripts/python.exe,then everything is good.