# Python Virtual Environment - Dodgy Files?

Tags: pycharm, python-venv

I'm new to Python and a little paranoid since malware scares a few weeks ago.

I created a project and configured a python interpreter by making a new virtual environment, which worked fine. The virtual environment shows in the file directory on the left of a Pycharm window in red, which I assume is because I haven't activated it. I now want to know, are the files in the venv Directory normal (there are many .exe files I can't find a reference to online)?

Many thanks for the help in advance!

[image: Files in venv]

[image: Files in venv 2]

[image: Files in venv 3]

I tried googling what files I should find in a venv but didn't find anything too useful. I would be grateful for reassurance/help.

Comment: Try to limit it to one question only here on StackOverflow. For the activation part maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal?rq=1).

Comment: if you are scared of malware then try to obtain your installers from trusted sources like `python.org` and `anaconda`, and when installing external libraries make sure you copy the installation command from the site of the trusted library, don't type it manually as people did use common typos in the library names to install malware packages into systems (as pip doesn't validate the security of all libraries), i didn't intend to scare you but these are the two things you need to be careful of when it comes to malware in python programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you install all python futures in these ways are safe :

1. `PIP3 install Python` from the **command prompt**
2. Install **Vscode** and after that from extensions
3. Install a complete **anaconda** package from that site to be free from all libraries in the future.

and as I saw your Sc,

> all those files are necessary to run python and virtual environments.

But there is a point: **Don't try to make several virtual environments**, because in the future you will be **confused between them**, and also your python version will be set on **each environment differently**!

notice: if you are a beginner, **try to work on VS CODE**. because it is very helpful and easy.