# Install NodeJS package locally

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

When i try to install package on my local directory using `npm install connect`,but it just keep pop up some warning about

> no such file or directory, open '/Users/felixfong/package.json'

But i don't not want to install package at my computer directory,i want to install at my local web app directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are inside your local web app directory when you run the `npm install connect` command?

```
cd app-directory/
npm install connect
```

Also ensure that a `package.json` file is also present in the `app-directory`.

If it isn't present, you can use `npm init` command to create the `package.json` file interactively.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go inside your project directory using 
Then you can check package.json. 
If package.json file is not there then [initialize npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) using the following command:

```
npm init
```

Then your can install the package using the following command:

```
npm install connect
```

'npm install connect' does not save the connect npm package in package.json file.

For saving the package into package.json file you have to givt --save option like:

```
npm install connect --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in web app's directory. Current path can be checked via command `pwd` in Linux and `cd` [in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607670/windows-shell-command-to-get-the-full-path-to-current-directory). Navigate to your web app directory if you are somewhere else. Check existence of `package.json` by listing the content of the folder. `ls` and `dir` can be used for ubuntu and windows respectively for listing content. Commands for ubuntu are as below:

```
pwd    
cd your-path/
ls
```

Now [Initialize npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) in your web app directory if `package.json` is not already existing there.

```
npm init
```

This will ask some information like:

- name of the app,
- its version,
- description,
- entry point,
- test command,
- git repo,
- keywords,
- author and
- license (if any)

You can select default values by leaving the fields empty if you aren't sure or confused about any field. Combining this information as json, npm will create a file named `package.json`

Just run the desired command now after initialization of npm or if its already initialized:

```
npm install connect
```