# wp-cli download wordpress core files without default wordpress themes twenty*

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

Using wp-cli [on Windows](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#installing-on-windows) all works fine.

When I am in project root folder I like to download the WordPress core files skipping all the WordPress default themes twenty*.

For that I use the command `wp core download --skip-themes --debug` however it always downloads all the default themes.

How can I get wp-cli to only really give me the core files **without** the included default WordPress themes?

Is there a wp-cli command for deleting folders perhaps?

If this cannot be done with wp-cli what other ways could I use to always automatically remove the default themes from the WordPress core download without actually going into the project folder?

Comment: For me, and I would assume many other devs coming from Windows, the wp-cli setup procedure for Windows is relevant. Was very happy to [have found that it being more detailed than the official docs](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/install-wp-cli-windows/). I am now including [the official setup procedure from wordpress.org](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#installing-on-windows) and would prefer for that to be left intact to help devs new to wp-cli get this working on Windows, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Default themes are part of the Wordpress distribution.

The `--skip-themes` flag is not meant for this, but to disable loading **installed** themes during `wp-cli` execution (in case there is some theme triggered logic you may want avoid executing).

There is no wp-cli command to delete files, that doesn't make a lot of sense. You can always delete them with the appropriate commands for your platform.

Comment: See edit please, perhaps there is another way one could use?

Comment: Your question is neither grunt nor node related. There are many ways to delete files and folders, that question is **too broad**, and out of scope for SO.

Comment: Thanks & removed tags.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a `rm -rf wp-content/themes/*`? This should do it:

```
wp core download && rm -rf wp-content/themes/*
```

*Eventually*, if you have to do this a alot, you could create your own script, let's say `wp-clean.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
wp core download && rm -rf wp-content/themes/*
```

Then `chmod +x wp-clean.sh` and you're set.

Edit, because I missed the *Windows* part (honestly I didn't even knew that wp cli works on Win :D).

```
wp core download && rmdir wp-content/themes/* /s
```

If you want to automate, just create a `.bat` file instead of `.sh` with only the above line.

Comment: Considering he's using windows, rm -rf would work nicely. ;)

Comment: And "how to delete files" is a horrible q&a for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry @yivi, Ionuț Staicu supplied what I am looking for helping with automation and hence gets the answer. Thank you Ionuț.

Comment: Glad to know you needed help  *deleting files*. :( But this answer is potentially **very dangerous** and wrong. This will delete **ALL YOUR THEMES**, not only the default ones

Comment: @yivi Read the question again and don't assume incorrectly. It is about wp-cli not about generally deleting files. No need to downvote, but if that floats your boat I don't mind. Having the core WordPress files without the default themes is what I am looking for and Ionut supplied the answer to that question. I am not going into further discussion. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @Iowtechsun, this answer doesn't address how skip theme downloads when using wp-cli (which you can't). It helps you _delete files_, which apparently you needed help with. Glad to know you found what you needed. Peace out. :)

Answer (score -1):

Make a batch (.bat) file with below code in the project folder and run.

This will download the latest WordPress core files to that project folder.

Then it will go to the `project folder/wp-content/themes` and delete **ALL FILES AND FOLDERS** from that `themes` folder.

**If** that `themes` folder **does not exist** the batch file will **exit without deleting** any files in that `themes` folder after an user confirmation.

```
call wp core download
set mypath=%~dp0wp-content\themes%
echo %mypath%
if exist "%mypath%" (
    cd %mypath%
    for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
)
pause
```

This will work, **however** the command prompt output will show `The directory name is invalid.` when going in the `%mypath%` after the WordPress core download has finished. I have no clue why this happens and might ask this in another question if nobody comments about this.

Reference:
[How to get the path of the batch script in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827567/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-batch-script-in-windows)

[Windows shell command to get the full path to current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607670/windows-shell-command-to-get-the-full-path-to-current-directory/17465137#17465137)

[Batch file. Delete all files and folders in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/batch-file-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/35183789#35183789)

https://indigotree.co.uk/automated-wordpress-installation-cmd/